# TypeError: Member "memories" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in struct CrowdFunding.Campaign storage pointer. mem=c.memories

Tags: remix

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity >=0.6.0 <0.9.0;

// Defines a new type with two fields.
// Declaring a struct outside of a contract allows
// it to be shared by multiple contracts.
// Here, this is not really needed.

struct Funder {
    address addr;
    uint amount;
}

struct Omoide {
        string mem;
        uint memId;
        address posteraddr;
    }

contract CrowdFunding {

    // Structs can also be defined inside contracts, which makes them
    // visible only there and in derived contracts.
    struct Campaign {
        address payable beneficiary;
        uint fundingGoal;
        uint numFunders;
        uint numMemories;
        uint amount;
        
        mapping (uint => Funder) funders;
        mapping (uint =>Omoide) Omoides;
    }
    
    uint numCampaigns;
    mapping (uint => Campaign) campaigns;

    function newCampaign(address payable beneficiary, uint goal) public returns (uint campaignID) {
        campaignID = numCampaigns++; // campaignID is return variable
        // We cannot use "campaigns[campaignID] = Campaign(beneficiary, goal, 0, 0)"
        // because the right hand side creates a memory-struct "Campaign" that contains a mapping.
        Campaign storage c = campaigns[campaignID];
        c.beneficiary = beneficiary;
        c.fundingGoal = goal;
        
    }

    function contribute(uint campaignID) public payable {
        Campaign storage c = campaigns[campaignID];
        // Creates a new temporary memory struct, initialised with the given values
        // and copies it over to storage.
        // Note that you can also use Funder(msg.sender, msg.value) to initialise.
        c.funders[c.numFunders++] = Funder({addr: msg.sender, amount: msg.value});
        c.amount += msg.value;
    }


    function checkGoalReached(uint campaignID) public returns (bool reached) {
        Campaign storage c = campaigns[campaignID];
        if (c.amount < c.fundingGoal)
            return false;
        uint amount = c.amount;
        c.amount = 0;
        c.beneficiary.transfer(amount);
        return true;
    }
    
    function addOmoide(uint campaignID,string memory Omoidetex) public  {
        Campaign storage c = campaigns[campaignID];
        c.Omoides[c.numMemories++]=Omoide({mem:Omoidetex,memId:c.numMemories,posteraddr:msg.sender});
        //Omoide is a essay to stack on "Campaign"


    }
     function seeOmoide(uint campaignID,uint numMemories) public returns(string memory mem) {
        Campaign storage c = campaigns[campaignID];
        mem=c.Omoides[numMemories].omo;


        
    }
}
```

solidity 0.6.0 on Remix IDE

I want to make a contract to display "Omoide" 's content(essay),
Omoide is a structure that can contain one or more in each campaign. It is managed by Mapping.

I would like to create an `addOmoideContract` that will add an 'Omoide' to a previously created 'Campaign' by entering the campaign number and the 'Omoide' body, and a `seeOmoideContract` that will output the Omoide body by entering the 'Campaign' number and the 'Omoide' number. I want to create a `seeOmoideContract` that outputs the Omoide itself by entering the 'Campaign' number and the 'Omoide' number. However, I get the following error and cannot do "seeOmoide".

```
contracts/CrowdFunding.sol:74:13: TypeError: Member "omo" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in struct Omoide storage ref.
mem=c.Omoides[numMemories].omo;
^------------------------^
```

I am not sure if it is because I am using "Mapping" or 'storage'. If you know what I should do to complete "seeOmoide" and for the future, I would appreciate it if you could tell me what I should do.

Comment: Side-note: having a mapping starting with an upper-case might be confusing, as CapWords style is rather used for contracts/interface, enum and struct
```mapping (uint =>Omoide) omoides;``` - see the styling guide from the docs: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.17/style-guide.html#naming-styles

Answer (score 0):

The struct Omoide has no `omo` members, here are the members you defined:

```
struct Omoide {
        string mem;
        uint memId;
        address posteraddr;
    }
```

I guess you want to access the string, which is named `mem`: `c.Omoides[numMemories].mem`

Comment: I miss it!Thank you !